# Ethereum Node, Lighthouse client error

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node, lighthouse

I am synching Ethereum full node (Geth + Lighthouse). I got the following error

```
CRIT Failed to start beacon node reason: Unable to open database:
 DBError { message: "Error { message: \"Corruption: 34 missing files; e.g.:
           /mnt/data/eth_node/lighthouse/beacon/beacon/freezer_db/000015.ldb\" }" }
```

your help is much appreciated.